# adding found maximum value on each column to new array (java)

Tags: java, arrays

After you search the maximum value on each column, how do you add the value found to a new array?

```
double cur[][] ={ 
        {  0,     0.25,   0.5},
        {  0.5,   0.75,   1},
        {  0.75,  1,      1},
        {  0,     0.25,   0.5},
        {  0.25,  0.5,    0.75},
        {  0,     0,      0.25},
        {  0.5,   0.75,   1}
};  

public void max1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cur[0].length; i++) { // i should be your column
        double max = cur[0][i];// assign 1st value of the column as max
        for (int j = 0; j < cur.length; j++){ // j is your row
            if (cur[j][i] > max){ // check the column elements instead of row elements
                max = cur[j][i];// get the column values 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how is your question related to netbeans?

Comment: you need to change the type of method, so it returns a double[ ][ ], not void, then you can use this method as you like

Comment: I use netbeans to code java application.

Comment: And you have also used a specific OS, but that does not make it relevant to the actual question. NetBeans tag removed.

Comment: whoops. I'm a beginner in this site and still unfamiliar with it's rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void max1() {
    double[] max_values = new double[cur[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < cur[0].length; i++) { // i should be your column
        double max = cur[0][i];// assign 1st value of the column as max
        for (int j = 0; j < cur.length; j++){ // j is your row
           if (cur[j][i] > max){ 
              max = cur[j][i];// get the column values 
           }
        }
        max_values[i] = max;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new array first and add the max element from each column into it as you get.

int i=0; float[] maximum=new float[3]; (since there are only 3 columns)

After the first 'for loop' where you get the maximum value from each column add this, maximum[i]=max & i++;

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    double[] columnMaxima = IntStream.range(0, cur[0].length)
            .mapToDouble(
                    i -> Stream.of(cur)
                            .mapToDouble(row -> row[i])
                            .max()
                            .getAsDouble())
            .toArray();
```